# Is there a Java.Swing equivalent to AS3's ADDED_TO_STAGE event?

Tags: java, swing

In AS3, there is an event that listens for when an object is added to the stage. This is useful for cases where, for example, some variables are not set until it is added on-screen. By waiting until the object has been added, you can assure that all of those variables are set.

Is there an equivalent in swing? For example, I have a function that relies on an objects getWidth function. Obviously, if I try to call this before the object is added on screen, this function will have problems because the width will be zero. I would like this function to be called as soon as the component is added and has a width. In as3, I would do something like:

```
myComponent.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, myFunction).
```

How would I do that in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your setup, a [`ComponentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) might be enough. There is [a section in The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) about `ComponentListener`s.

Another way of initializing stuff as soon as it is displayed is overriding the `paintComponent` method and performing the setup on the first invocation.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble implementing it, but I'm pretty sure that's just me. ComponentListener sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` is different from `Java`. There are no function objects in `Java` and hence no `JavaScript`-style callbacks. In `Swing` you can react to events related to showing/adding of components by adding [`ComponentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) or [`ContainerListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ContainerListener.html)to either component or container via `addComponentListener()` and `addContainerListener()` methods.